# Firestore - Simple full text search solution

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I know that firestore doesn't support full text search and it giving us solution to use third party services. However I found a simple solution to *simple* "full text search" and I think this might help others who doesn't want to use third party services as me for such a simple task. 
I'm trying to search for company name which is saved in firestore collection under my companyName which can be in any format for example "My Awesome Company". When adding new company with companyName or updating a value in companyName I'm also saving searchName with it which is the same value as company name but in lower case without spaces

```
searchName: removeSpace(companyName).toLowerCase()
```

removeSpace is my simple custom function which remove all spaces from a text

```
export const removeSpace = (string) => {
    return string.replace(/\s/g, '');
}
```

That turns our company name to **myawesomecompany** which is saved in searchName

Now I've got a firestore function to search for company which indexing through searchName and returning companyName. Minumum search value is a searched value without last character and maximum search value is a searched value with added "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz" transformed to lower case. That means if you search for **My Aw** then min value will be **mya** and max value will be **myawzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz**

```
exports.handler = ((data) => {
const searchValue = data.value.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase()
const minName = searchValue.substr(0, searchName.length-1)
const maxName = searchValue + "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
let list = []
const newRef = db.collection("user").where("profile.searchName", ">=", minName).where("profile.searchName", "<=", maxName)
return newRef.get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        list.push({ name: doc.data().profile.companyName})
    })
    return list
})
})
```

I didn't have time to fully test it but so far it works without any problems. Please let me know if you spot anything wrong with it. Now the question is

Is "z" character the highest value character in firestore or is there any other more decent way to add into the search value maximum amount without adding "zzzzzzzzzzzzz"?

Comment: After some testing I found this approach not very reliable. I would recommend to use array option below

Comment: https://fireblog.io/blog/post/which-full-text-search-index-do-i-use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little modification of previous answer I have made another simple text search. I'm saving keyword to an array instead of saving it in object like this

```
nameIndex: textIndexToArray(companyName)
```

where textIndexToArray is my custom function

```
export const textIndexToArray = (str) => {
const string = str.trim().replace(/ +(?= )/g,'')
let arr = []
for (let i = 0; i < string.trim().length; i++) {
    arr.push(string.substr(0,i+1).toLowerCase());
}
return arr
}
```

which transfer a text into array. For example

```
"My Company"
```

will return

```
[m, my, my , my c, my co, my com, my comp, my compa, my compan, my company]
```

with nameIndex saved in firestore we can simply query the data thorough nameIndex and return companyName

```
exports.handler = ((data) => {
const searchValue = data.value.toLowerCase()
let list = []
const newRef = db.collection("user").where("nameIndex", "array-contains", searchValue)
return newRef.get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        list.push({ name: doc.data().companyName, })
    })
    return list
})
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I like your decision to preprocess the text so that it can be queried, but you could provide for a more flexible search by storing lowercase keywords with the users and searching those.  In other words, transform:

```
"My Awesome Company"
```

to...

```
{ my: true, awesome: true, company: true }
```

...and test against that.

When adding/updating the property:

```
// save keywords on the user
let keywords = {}
companyName.split(' ').forEach(word => keywords[word.toLowerCase()] = true)
```

When querying:

```
let searchKeywords = userInputString.split(' ').map(word => word.toLowerCase())

let collection = db.collection("user")
searchKeywords.forEach(keyword => { 
  collection = collection.where(`keywords.${keyword}` , '==' , true);
});
```

Comment: hmm.... I haven't thought about this way however what if a user would search for an incomplete keyword lets say in my example if the searched value is only **m**  then it would return null.

Comment: yes.  that's right.  it probably wouldn't make sense to include partial keywords in the object, but you could.  you could also include misspellings, depending on your requirements.

Comment: I like this idea... I think that that is too complicated for simple text search but you gave me a big clue for another complex search I also need to accomplish in my project. Thanks

Comment: The more I'm thinking about your idea the more I like it. And therefore I have changed my search with a little modification. However the idea is the same and I believe that it can be modified for more complex and custom searching

Comment: DEAR READER, JUST BE CAREFUL about indexing. `collection.where('keywords.${keyword}' , '==' , true);` part of this answer will lead to an index creation for each of the `keyword` of `searchKeywords` array.